# Ubuntu Php Locale ru_RU not working

Tags: php, date, locale

**Code:**

```
<?php

      setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');

      $date_ru = strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime('2018-01-31'));

      echo($date_ru);

?>
```

**Outputs:**

1) *Local Server:* 31 января 2018

2) *Remote Server:* 31 ������ 2018

(exactly those strange symbols instead of month-name).

**Settings:**

I've checked locales installed with `local -a` and run `php -i` to get info about both servers.

*Local Server:*

- ru_RU
- ru_RU.CP1251
- ru_RU.CP866
- ru_RU.ISO8859-5
- ru_RU.KOI8-R
- ru_RU.UTF-8

... and all the rest possible locales in all languages...

- $_SERVER['LANG'] => ru_RU.UTF-8
- PHP Version => 7.1.12

*Remote Server:*

- C
- C.UTF-8
- en_US.utf8
- POSIX
- ru_RU
- ru_RU.iso88595
- ru_RU.utf8
- $_SERVER['LANG'] => ru_RU.UTF-8
- PHP Version => 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

**How can I get output on the remote server to be the same as on the local one ?**

---

Update:
If I change to `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');`

*Local Server:* 31 января 2018 (as before change)

*Remote Server:* 31 Январь 2018

Although I don't get strange symbols here, the result is not satisfactory. 
the last letter here is the most important. 'январ**я**' is genetive case (what I want) when 'Январь' is nominative (not what I need).

Comment: You can check what the current locale setting is on your local server with something like `var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"));` and then use that result to set the locale on the remote server. If you're still having an issue after that then it's an encoding mismatch somewhere between where PHP ends and the pixels are put on your screen.

Comment: Also, in the case of encoding problems such as this you should use something like `bin2hex()` or hexdump to compare actual byte values and not what your browser/console/etc interpret them as.

Comment: Hi, Sammitch, thank you. dd(setlocale(LC_ALL, "")); gave ""ru_RU.UTF-8" for local and "C" for remote... I checked and see that I have already changed the locale in /etc/default/locale from LANG=us_US to LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 (i thought this was a proper way to change ubuntu's locale to what I need). Do you know the better way to change servers locale?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that Ubuntu's server package used different locales than those I had in my local environment.
I couldn't import locales from my local to Ubuntu (wonder if it's possible at all), so i just wrote a workaround (simple function to convert month-names like 'Январь' to 'января' etc..)

```
function convert($str) {

      $rus = array('/январь/ui', '/февраль/ui', '/март/ui', '/апрель/ui', '/май/ui', '/июнь/ui', '/июль/ui', '/август/ui', '/сентябрь/ui', '/октябрь/ui', '/ноябрь/ui', '/декабрь/ui');
      $lat = array('января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря');
      // return str_ireplace($rus, $lat, $str);
      return preg_replace($rus, $lat, $str);

}
```