# Set Default Locale on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, utf-8, locale, ubuntu-16.04

I have uploaded a project to ubuntu server (16.04)
My project is written in PHP and I have some pages where locale settings for languages are very important. Everything is working good on my local server, but date months name are outputted wrongly on remote server (details here: 
[Ubuntu Php Locale ru_RU not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346246/ubuntu-php-locale-ru-ru-not-working?noredirect=1#comment83680658_48346246))

I think that mistake is due to my local server using a different locale than remote one. In PHP,

> The return value of setlocale() depends on the system that PHP is
>   running. It returns exactly what the system setlocale function returns
>   [php setlocale() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

This code is supposed to show the system default locale:

```
<?php 
dd(setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));
?>
```

outputs:

- Local Server: "ru_RU.UTF-8"
- Remote Server: "C"

I've edited etc/default/locale on remote server to LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8, but it didnt' help.

**How can I change my Ubuntu default locale to ru_RU.UTF-8?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that locale 'ru_RU.UTF' on my local development server and on remote one (UBUNTU) were totally different. I couldn't import locales from local to remote, so I just created a work-around function.

```
public static function convert($str) {


  $rus = array('/январь/ui', '/февраль/ui', '/март/ui', '/апрель/ui', '/май/ui', '/июнь/ui', '/июль/ui', '/август/ui', '/сентябрь/ui', '/октябрь/ui', '/ноябрь/ui', '/декабрь/ui');
  $lat = array('января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря');
  return preg_replace($rus, $lat, $str);

  }
```